# Custom error message for unless validation in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following validation in my model:

```
validates :cep, presence: true, :unless => lambda { |o| o.location }
```

How can I customize the error message that shows when the validation fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in a [`message`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message) option to the `validates` method.

```
validates :cep, presence: { message: 'Your custom error message' }, unless: lambda { |o| o.location }
```